# Meaning and usage of -つう tsuu?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

E.g.目の光つうのか、見ているさきつうのか。

Seems similar to ふうに？よう？

Edit: Seems つー is another ver of という.

But what meaning does the つー in this sentence mean? This isn't part of the "what someone said or what it's called" part of the meaning of という.
Is this the "emphasis" meaning of という?

Comment: The others only covered what つー stands for and provided examples for the meaning of という that do not match my particular question hence it is not a duplicate.

Comment: https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-to-iu-kato-iu-ka/ http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-to-iu-ka/